# How to determine newline while reading a file

Tags: autoit

I have an AutoIt script that works, mostly.  Reads a file, writes out what I want, but it does not preserve the original newline character.  If I read a UNIX format file (LF only), it will write out a Windows format file (CR and LF).

Short of switching to something more robust, like Python, how do I solve this in AutoIt?

```
Opt("MustDeclareVars", 1)   ;0 = no, 1 = require pre-declare

#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Local $gInPath = $CmdLine[1]
Local $NumberOfLines = $CmdLine[2]
Local $gInDrive, $gInDir, $gInFName, $gInExt, $gOutPath
Local $gMsgBoxTitle = "Error in " & @ScriptName
Local $InLine
Local $LineCount
Local $oFileIn
Local $oFileOut
Local $FileStringAppend

If FileExists($gInPath) Then
Else
    MsgBox(4096, $gMsgBoxTitle, "This file does not exist" & @CRLF & $gInPath)
    Exit
EndIf

_PathSplit($gInPath, $gInDrive, $gInDir, $gInFName, $gInExt)

If $NumberOfLines >= 1000000 Then
    $FileStringAppend = $NumberOfLines / 1000000 & "M"
ElseIf $NumberOfLines >= 1000 Then
    $FileStringAppend = $NumberOfLines / 1000 & "K"
Else
    $FileStringAppend = $NumberOfLines
EndIf

$gOutPath = _PathMake($gInDrive, $gInDir, $gInFName & "_" & $FileStringAppend, $gInExt)
If FileExists($gOutPath) Then
    MsgBox(4096, $gMsgBoxTitle, "File already exists" & @CRLF & $gOutPath)
    Exit
EndIf

$oFileIn = FileOpen($gInPath, 0)
$oFileOut = FileOpen($gOutPath, 1)

; Check if file opened for reading OK
If $oFileIn = -1 Then
    MsgBox(4096, $gMsgBoxTitle, "Unable to open file for read" & @CRLF & $gInPath)
    Exit
EndIf

; Check if file opened for writing OK
If $oFileOut = -1 Then
    MsgBox(4096, $gMsgBoxTitle, "Unable to open file for write." & @CRLF & $gOutPath)
    Exit
EndIf

; Read in lines of text until the EOF is reached
$LineCount = 0
While 1
    $InLine = FileReadLine($oFileIn)
    $LineCount += 1
    If @error = -1 Then ExitLoop
    If $LineCount > $NumberOfLines Then ExitLoop
    FileWriteLine($oFileOut, $InLine & @CRLF)
WEnd

FileClose($oFileIn)
FileClose($oFileOut)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the function documentation at this link - https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileWriteLine.htm . It appears you can leave off the `& @CRLF` in your `FileWriteLine` command.

AutoIt should use the same line terminator that is read in, or

> "If the line does NOT end in @CR or @LF then a DOS linefeed (@CRLF)
>   will be automatically added."

Comment: It is defaulting in a @CRLF rather than using the Newline character(s) from the FileReadLine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up. It works, but I'm not sure it's the cleanest.

```
Opt("MustDeclareVars", 1)   ;0 = no, 1 = require pre-declare

#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Local $gInPath = $CmdLine[1]
Local $NumberOfLines = $CmdLine[2]
Local $gInDrive, $gInDir, $gInFName, $gInExt, $gOutPath
Local $gMsgBoxTitle = "Error in " & @ScriptName
Local $InLine
Local $LineCount
Local $oFileIn
Local $oFileOut
Local $FileStringAppend
Local Const $CHAR_READ_BLOCK = 100
Local $CharsRead = 0
Local $CrFound = 0
Local $LfFound = 0
Local $Newline
Local $InBlock

If FileExists($gInPath) Then
Else
    MsgBox(4096, $gMsgBoxTitle, "This file does not exist" & @CRLF & $gInPath)
    Exit
EndIf

_PathSplit($gInPath, $gInDrive, $gInDir, $gInFName, $gInExt)

If $NumberOfLines >= 1000000 Then
    $FileStringAppend = $NumberOfLines / 1000000 & "M"
ElseIf $NumberOfLines >= 1000 Then
    $FileStringAppend = $NumberOfLines / 1000 & "K"
Else
    $FileStringAppend = $NumberOfLines
EndIf

$gOutPath = _PathMake($gInDrive, $gInDir, $gInFName & "_" & $FileStringAppend, $gInExt)
If FileExists($gOutPath) Then
    MsgBox(4096, $gMsgBoxTitle, "File already exists" & @CRLF & $gOutPath)
    Exit
EndIf

$oFileIn = FileOpen($gInPath, 0)
$oFileOut = FileOpen($gOutPath, 1)

; Check if file opened for reading OK
If $oFileIn = -1 Then
    MsgBox(4096, $gMsgBoxTitle, "Unable to open file for read" & @CRLF & $gInPath)
    Exit
EndIf

; Check if file opened for writing OK
If $oFileOut = -1 Then
    MsgBox(4096, $gMsgBoxTitle, "Unable to open file for write." & @CRLF & $gOutPath)
    Exit
EndIf

While $CrFound = 0 And $LfFound = 0
    $CharsRead += $CHAR_READ_BLOCK
    $InBlock = FileRead($oFileIn, $CharsRead)
    If StringRight($InBlock, 1) = @CR Then
        $InBlock = $InBlock & FileRead($oFileIn, $CharsRead)
    EndIf

    $CrFound = StringInStr($InBlock, @CR)
    $LfFound = StringInStr($InBlock, @LF)

    If $CrFound > 0 And $LfFound > 0 Then
        $Newline = @CRLF
    ElseIf $CrFound > 0 Then
        $Newline = @CR
    Else
        $Newline = @LF
    EndIf
WEnd

; Read first line of text
$InLine = FileReadLine($oFileIn, 1)
$LineCount = 1
FileWriteLine($oFileOut, $InLine & $Newline)

; Read in lines of text until the EOF is reached
While 1
    $InLine = FileReadLine($oFileIn)
    $LineCount += 1
    If @error = -1 Then ExitLoop
    If $LineCount > $NumberOfLines Then ExitLoop
    FileWriteLine($oFileOut, $InLine & $Newline)
WEnd

FileClose($oFileIn)
FileClose($oFileOut)
```